# Clicking "Back" button from a page showing a PDF in Firefox and Chrome causes header to appear in the <body> tag

Tags: php, pdf, header, http-headers

I'm running into a very strange error in Firefox and Chrome. The error doesn't occur in Safari. I'm displaying a PDF on a page with the following code (works fine):

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($pdfPath));
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $pdfId . '.pdf"');

readfile($pdfPath);
```

The PDF loads up beautifully, but when I click the back button in the browser (Firefox and Chrome), the page that I jump back to has the HTTP header included in the body tag.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 08 Mar 2011 00:18:47 GMT Server: Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) PHP/5.2.13 DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.0.63 OpenSSL/0.9.7l X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.13 Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Content-Length: 7010 Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=92 Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: text/html
```

This header is for the current page (not the page that displayed the PDF). In debugging, I printed out the body tag with the following jQuery code:

```
console.log($('body').html());
```

The header appears before any other content in the body. Any ideas as to what could be causing this rogue header to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what was going on, and the fix was quite simple. I just added an exit() after the readfile(), so the final code ended up looking like this:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($pdfPath));
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $pdfId . '.pdf"');

readfile($pdfPath);
exit();
```